# zf3 __construct() not working

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework3

I've created a module with name *Commerce* in zend 3 which is working fine. Now when I inject a dependency through `__construct()` it throws error

> Too few arguments to function
>   Commerce\Controller\IndexController::__construct(), 0 passed in
>   /var/www/html/zf3/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/Factory/InvokableFactory.php
>   on line 30 and exactly 1 expected

Here is the controller code.

```
<?php

namespace Commerce\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Commerce\Model\Commerce;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    private $commerce;

    /**
     * IndexController constructor.
     * @param Commerce $commerce
     */
    public function __construct(Commerce $commerce)
    {
        $this->commerceModel = $commerce;
    }


    public function indexAction()
    {
    return new ViewModel();
    }

}
```

`module.config.php` code

```
<?php

namespace Commerce;

use Zend\Router\Http\Literal;
use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;

return [
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'home' => [
                'type' => Literal::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'commerce' => [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/commerce[/:action][/:id]',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class
        ],
    ],
    'view_manager' => [
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => [
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'commerce/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/commerce/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ],
        'template_path_stack' => [
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Where is the issue? `zend-di` is already installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is caused in line

```
Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class
```

this does not provide a "Commerce\Model\Commerce" to the constructor of your IndexController. You need to change this to provide the dependency:

```
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        Controller\IndexController::class => function($container) {
            return new Controller\IndexController(
                $container->get(\Commerce\Model\Commerce::class)
            );
        },
    ],
],
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        \Commerce\Model\Commerce::class =>  function($sm) {
            /* provide any dependencies if needed */
            /* Create the model here. */
            return new \Commerce\Model\Commerce($dependencies);
        },
    ]
],
```

The best approach is to provide its own factory for your Commerce\Model\Commerce class, as seen above in the setting 'factories' of 'service_manager'.

EDIT: as request, if you want to do everything inside the controller Factory, here is a simple example:

```
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        Controller\IndexController::class => function($container) {
            $dbAdapter = $container->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
            $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
            $tableGateway = new TableGateway('commerceTableName', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);

            return new Controller\IndexController(
                new \Commerce\Model\Commerce($tableGateway)
            );
        },
    ],
],
```

Comment: It's working but it looks like a lot of work because I have to define them at 2 places (both in controller and module.config.php file). Is there a way through which I have to define them in controller only?

Comment: Yes, there is. You can skip defining a factory for "\Commerce\Model\Commerce", just create it in the controller factory: return new Controller\IndexController(new \Commerce\Model\Commerce($dependencies));

Comment: Can you please add this alternative in your answer with an example?

Comment: Yes, a simple example added.